# One Netgear GS716T switch port, connected to an HP CLJ 2605dn printer, triggers SNMP down/up traps every few minutes

Tags: switch, hp-laserjet, snmp

The port only goes down for a few seconds, then comes back up. A few minutes later, it does the same thing. The printer functions normally.

- All the other ports on the switch are fine.
- I've tried moving it to a different port and it does the same thing.
- I've looked into power management settings and there are none for this printer.      - I've also tried changing the switch port and the printer's NIC from auto-negotiate to 100Full

I'm thinking it's a bad cable. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the cable?

Comment: @Darth: Not yet.  I'll swap the patch cable as soon as I can find a replacement.  The other possibility is the main run for that port, which is the length of the building, so replacing it will be a non-trivial task.  As such I've been hoping to avoid it.

Comment: @Darth: Replaced the network cable between the printer and the wall jack and it didn't help.  I guess the only thing left is to move the printer to another jack temporarily - as a test.

Comment: Did you terminate the plugs, with the wires order to spec?  http://www.iplocation.net/tools/rj45-wiring.php

Comment: @NevinWilliams: I didn't make the patch cables or the long run between the jack and the switch, but I did test them all with an Ethernet cable tester and they were all fine.

Comment: Just take a look at one, and see if its colour coding matches the conventional standard I linked to...  I ran into similar misbehaviour when I started a job that had me working directly with field-techs; they were making their own cables, they were testing fine, but they weren't using the right combinations of twisted pairs.

Comment: @NevinWilliams: I'll do that next time I'm at the location. I'm pretty sure that the cables were all made to **a** standard, though it may not be the one you referenced. For instance, the standard in Canada seems to be different from the US standard.

Comment: The only experience with a bad Canadian-made cable (other than the ones I've made myself) were two short jumpers a Shaw-Toronto tech had made to connect two @Home Motorola MCNS cable routers, in '98 or so:  They had the interesting property of refusing to pass more than 3 pings sourced by a cisco router, regardless of pattern, packet length, proximity, or IOS version.  They had no trouble with pings sourced from servers, even cisco-style.  I asked the tech to ship me the jumpers after we finally isolated the trouble, but ...

Answer (score 0):

Can you temporarily move the printer to the switch or use a different cable run?  Are duplex and speed Auto or hard set on both switch and printer?  Have seen a problem with duplex and speed on auto.  I know it is supposed to work and normally does.  Had one that was fine for ages and suddenly wanted both hard set.

Comment: Moving the printer close to the switch to bypass the long cable run makes sense from a troubleshooting standpoint, but it's impractical in reality because the printer is used throughout the day.  I suppose I could try that after hours some time.  I'll keep that idea for later.  As I mentioned in the original question, I've tried setting both ends to 100Full and it didn't help.